# Query - Update table rows at one go with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table  - Table1 (lat,lat_appx,long,long_appx,.....), I want to update this table.
Update the respective lat_appx column by reading first 6 character from respective lat column for each row.
I want to do same for long_appx. I have thousands of rows so manually it impossible.

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update your_table
set lat_appx = substring(lat, 1, 6),
    long_appx = substring(`long`, 1, 6)
```